# Matrix Valued Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I was studying Kalman Filters lately and came across an interesting concept. A textbook explained that if you have two random vectors X in $R^n$ in $R^m$ then you can define a sort of "inner product" as the expected value of the outer product $\left<X,Y\right> = E[XY^T]$. It seems odd at first since this a matrix and not a number but the properties of inner products still hold with a little bit of modification. We have the symmetry $\left<X,Y\right> = \left<Y,X\right>^T$ and even the positivity $\left<X,X\right> > 0$ (unless $X$ is degenerate).

What's more the kalman filter becomes much easier to understand in this context (in essence it becomes a generalization of gram-schmidt algorithm). I thought this was reall cool but I'm curious about whether anyone has formalized and studied this sort of inner product in more depth. Are there other contexts in which it is useful?

Comment: Looks a lot like the Frobenius inner product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product

Comment: That outputs a scalar not a matrix.

Comment: How are you defining a matrix-valued expectation? It's normally done with Lebesgue measure which is an extended real number.

Comment: When $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then $XY^T$ a  random $n \times m$ matrix and $E[XY^T]$ is  an $n \times m$ matrix.